# Using Microsoft Release Management with Team City

Tags: teamcity, ms-release-management

Is it possible to use Microsoft Release Management Server with the build artifact output from a Team City build?

- And perhaps optionally have Team City trigger the first step in a release?

*I've only seen documentation which steps though builds with TFS build.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. If you set your components to "Builds Externally", you can specify a path to your Team City binary drop location. Then, at the time of triggering a release, you'll specify the exact version of the binaries to deploy from that location.

You can have Team City trigger a release from RM by using the *ReleaseManagementBuild.exe* tool. It's located in the Release Management installation folder

You can trigger a release for a TeamCity-generated build by running *ReleaseManagementBuild.exe -rt "YourReleaseTemplateName" -pl "\YourTeamCityDropLocation\Whatever\"*

Related blog, from Jonathan Rajotte at Microsoft on the RM team:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/04/release-management-continuous-deployment-with-visual-studio-online-and-any-ci-systems.aspx

Comment: Related blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/04/release-management-continuous-deployment-with-visual-studio-online-and-any-ci-systems.aspx

Comment: @joerage Perfect, thanks! I updated the answer to have that. I was actually looking for it but couldn't find it. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using vNext deployments (PowerShell DSC) I've written a blog post on how to trigger this from Team City here:

http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2015/01/14/trigger-visual-studio-release-management-vnext-from-teamcity.aspx

It uses the new REST API that was introduced in 2013 update 3.